# What to use instead of the content_save_pre filter?

Tags: filters

I read on Adam Brown's website that the `content_save_pre` filter [is depreciated](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/content_save_pre) as of WordPress 3.8 - is this true? It doesn't say it on the [official codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre) for `content_save_pre` so I'm skeptical. If it is depreciated, which filter would I use to edit the content after I press Publish/Update but before it writes it to the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What Adam Brown's site says is that the hook no longer appears in 3.8.  I `grep`ed a 3.9 and found:

```
bash-4.2# grep -Rni 'content_save_pre' *
wp-includes/kses.php:1327: * The wp_filter_post_kses() function is added to the 'content_save_pre',
wp-includes/kses.php:1344:      add_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
wp-includes/kses.php:1370:      remove_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
wp-includes/default-filters.php:89:foreach ( array( 'content_save_pre', 'excerpt_save_pre', 'comment_save_pre', 'pre_comment_content' ) as $filter ) {
```

Interestingly the filter is not *applied* anywhere, but is still *used* by the Core in several places. That would be a big oversight. If you look around a bit more you will find this:

```
http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/{$field_no_prefix}_save_pre
```

So `grep` again a bit less rigidly and right at the bottom:

```
wp-includes/post.php:2010:                      $value = apply_filters("{$field_no_prefix}_save_pre", $value);
```

It is a dynamic filter, which I assume is why Adam Brown lost track. This is confirmed by the Codex itself:

> The "content_save_pre" filter is part of a group of dynamic filters that allow you to sanitize content prior to saving it in the
>   database. This filter runs in wp-admin.
>
> ```
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/content_save_pre
> ```

I believe that that is the hook you are looking for. In other words, `content_save_pre` should still work. It is generated dynamically but should still work.

Comment: that's interesting, thanks for looking into it. I had found the `{$field_no_prefix}_save_pre` but I wasn't sure how it worked. Thanks!